# How to use metric filter in cloudwatch logs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

how can i display only the person name in cloudwatch dashbaord.

log :  message:"Personname ABC",

able to filter the message using the query..filter @message like /Personname / |
display message

please help to display only the name i dont like to display'Personname' just the name ABC.

Answer (score 0):

CloudWatch [Metric filters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/MonitoringLogData.html) are not used to extract text, they're used for counting the number of occurrences for a specific condition i.e. when the Persons name is ABC

> After the CloudWatch Logs agent begins publishing log data to Amazon CloudWatch, you can begin searching and filtering the log data by creating one or more metric filters. Metric filters define the terms and patterns to look for in log data as it is sent to CloudWatch Logs. CloudWatch Logs uses these metric filters to turn log data into numerical CloudWatch metrics that you can graph or set an alarm on. You can use any type of CloudWatch statistic, including percentile statistics, when viewing these metrics or setting alarms.

If you're wanting to analyze your data take a look at using [CloudWatch Logs Insights](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/AnalyzingLogData.html).

Comment: with the current query i am able to display 'Personname ABC' in dashboard. i like to display only ABC how can i do that.. Parse will work?

Comment: What is your query? Could you also provide an example query?

Answer (score 0):

As @ChrisWilliams explained, the metric filters serve different purpose.

One way of filtering the logs is through [log subscriptions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/Subscriptions.html):

> You can use subscriptions to get access to a **real-time feed** of log events from CloudWatch Logs and have it **delivered to other services** such as a Amazon Kinesis stream, Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose stream, or AWS Lambda for custom processing, analysis, or loading to other systems.

Using subscriptions you could feed your logs into **Kiensis Firehose** in real-time, transform it using [firehose transforamtions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/firehose/latest/dev/data-transformation.html) into format you desire and save it to S3. This way you can process the logs in a way you want and have them delivered to S3 for further analysis or long term storage.

Alternatively, can feed the logs directly to a **lambda function**, and from there you can do what you wish.